# Ionic local storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem with Ionic using local storage , when I try to save an array it automatically convert it from an object to a string like shown below :

[image]

Can anyone please help me ?
Here is the code I'm using :

```
angular.module('mainApp')
    .factory('cartFactory', function () {
        var cart = [{
            'title': 'titre2',
            'pic': './img/catalogue/k2.jpg'
        }];
        console.log("Type 1:" , typeof(cart) );
        console.log("Content 1:" , cart);
        window.localStorage.setItem('cart', cart);
        var cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart');
        console.log("Type 2:" , typeof(cart) );
        console.log("Content 2:" , cart);

        return {
            all: function () {
                return cart;
            },
            get: function (index) {
                return cart[index];
            },
            add: function (product) {
                cart.push(product);
            },
            remove: function (product) {
                var index = cart.indexOf(product);
                cart.splice(index, 1);
            }
        };
    });
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage only supports strings, the best bet you might have is to convert your array to a json array, and then read it back:

```
localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

//...
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
```

Comment: Thank you ! that was so simple